# Safari xhr drag'n'drop file upload seems to occur twice

Tags: javascript, ajax, upload, safari, webfaction

It can be related to Webfaction configuration (they have nginx proxy, and my app is webpy running under apache2+mod_wsgi) because it works in my dev cherrypy server.

Here are some bits from javascript code I use for upload:

```
/* Bind drop events */
    $(this).bind({
        "dragover": function(e){
            var dt = e.originalEvent.dataTransfer;
            if(!dt) return;
            if($.browser.webkit) dt.dropEffect = 'copy';
            $(this).addClass("active");
        return false;
        },
        "dragleave": function(e){
            $(this).removeClass("active")
        },
        "dragenter": function(e){return false;},
        "drop": function(e){
            var dt = e.originalEvent.dataTransfer;
            if(!dt&&!dt.files) return;
            $(this).removeClass("active")
            var files = dt.files;
            for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
                upload(files[i]);
            }
            return false;
        }
    })

/* Upload function code cut down to the basic  */
function upload(file) {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var xhr_upload = xhr.upload;
    xhr_upload.addEventListener("progress", function(e){
        if( e.lengthComputable ) {
            var p = Math.round(e.loaded * 100 / e.total );
            if(e.loaded == e.total){
              console.log( e );
            }
        }
    }, false);
    xhr_upload.addEventListener( "load", function( e ){}, false);
    xhr_upload.addEventListener( "error", function( error ) { alert("error: " + error); }, false);
    xhr.open( 'POST', url, true);
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function ( e ) {   };
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
    xhr.setRequestHeader("X-Requested-With", "XMLHttpRequest");
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", file.type);
    xhr.setRequestHeader("X-File-Name", encodeURIComponent(file.fileName));
    xhr.setRequestHeader("X-File-Size", file.fileSize);
    xhr.send(file);
}
```

If I fill span with percentage value in progress event, then in Safari it goes from 0% to 100%, then from 50% to 100%, and after that upload is done. Chrome and Firefox are OK.

`e.loaded == e.total` is reached twice per upload, since I see this in my console log:

[console log http://img824.imageshack.us/img824/4363/screenshot20110827at101.png](http://img824.imageshack.us/img824/4363/screenshot20110827at101.png)

In the first logged event totalSize is equal to the size of file, but in the second it is twice as much.

Comment: It might be helpful to see how and where the drop event is triggered. I have to wonder if there are two drop events being fired for some reason.

Comment: Have you checked the contents of `files`?

Comment: @Barum, backend gets correct files with the exact size, but the files seem to be transferred twice per upload.

Comment: @Ryan, I've updated the question with drop event bind excerpt. I don't see this as a problem, since in my code upload creates <li> element for every file dropped, and I definitely don't see the same file being dropped twice.

Comment: @Andrey - What, in this case, is `this`? What selectors are you using?

Comment: @Ryan, Uploader is implemented as jquery plugin, and is tightly coupled with the cms project. Basically `this` can be any element selected by jquery, in my case it is `$( ".ui-storage-documents" )`.

Comment: You might consider using an HTTP inspector to see whether there are actually multiple requests and responses happening, and what they look like.

Comment: Do you know how to debug Safari protocol-level? I need to get the dump of data that is going between Safari and the server. Network tab in Web Inspector shows that only one request is made.

Comment: `progress` is not a part of any standard yet, so Safari can afford it to be buggy. http://www.w3.org/TR/progress-events/

Comment: @c69 Its ok if only progress state display is incorrect, but it seems that Safari uploads the file twice, which is twice more time to wait for upload.

Comment: hmm.. maybe this guy is right - Safari/Windows is just a buggy pieace of crap .. http://www.smilingsouls.net/Blog/20110413023355.html

Comment: @c69, my Safari is OS X one. The link is interesting, thanks!

Comment: Although likely unrelated to the issue you're experiencing, the line `if(!dt&&!dt.files) return;` should be `if(!dt||!dt.files) return;` in order to prevent errors if `dt` is undefined or unintended results if only `dt.files` is undefined.

Comment: @Karthik, thanks, I will fix it in my code.

Answer (score 1):

I would try heavy use of the console to get to the bottom of something like this. Put a console statement at every major piece of code displaying something meaningful each time:

```
for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) 
{
console.log(files[i]+", "+i);    
upload(files[i])
};
```

and then again inslide your `upload()`.

Comment: I've already tried to log different variables, but it seems to me everything is happening behind the scene.

Comment: I'm not saying you should use it to check variable values, but to check the sequence of execution of your code. You do not have to use a variable for that - you can use plain text. It's pretty straightforward, and helps to resolve logical / sequencing errors in your code.

Comment: To check the sequence of execution I usually set breakpoints, Script tab in Safari's Web Inspector allows to do that. But that didn't help me to find the problem in my code.

Comment: the trouble with breakpoints is that it does exactly that. It breaks the flow, and requires you to make it continue to the next breakpoint. Far slower than actually printing the sequence as it occurs, and I get a headache trying to remember where I've been. In fact by definition, that's exactly the purpose of a (console)log.

Answer (score 0):

Could it have something to do with having a variable and a function with the same name (upload)? In Javascript, you can use the name of a function as a reference to it. Try renaming your `xhr.upload` variable and see if it fixes anything.

Comment: Changed `upload` to `xhr_upload`, but it didn't solve my problem. Thanks for this correction.